# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'taran'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have started this today and received this over again and again and I have recreated the user also but it is not working. Please help me to debug it.

This is my app.py

```html
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://taran:1234@localhost/flask'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    body = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now())


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    title = request.form.get('title')
    body = request.form.get('body')

    post = Post(title = title, body = body)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug= True)
```

This is the error coming
[image]

Please help

Comment: Bad credentials or missing (host) permissions.

Comment: Can you open mysql in your terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

check if the password to access your SQL database is correct or else try changing your SQL root password to something else and try again. The above error is very similar to the one we commonly encounter while logging on to a website with the wrong password or username.

for changing the root password see the below video
https://youtu.be/izMuHGwXyjQ

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a password try either of this

Option 01:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DB_URI='mysql://root@localhost:<PORT>/<DB NAME>'
```

Option 02:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DB_URI='mysql://root:''@localhost:<PORT>/<DB NAME>'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to change the driver?

```py
#from
'mysql://taran:1234@localhost/flask' 
#to 
'mysql+pymysql://taran:1234@localhost/flask'
```

(I assume you've checked credentials already)